# Heroku sporadically returns "hostname" not found

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, heroku, nserror

I'm creating an iOS app that uses a Rails API backend on Heroku.  Periodically (one every 20 API calls), heroku cannot be found.  The following NSError is returned:

```
Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1003 "A server with the specified hostname could not be found." UserInfo=0x755ce00 {NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://xxx.herokuapp.com/api/v1/matchups, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://xxx.herokuapp.com/api/v1/matchups, NSLocalizedDescription=A server with the specified hostname could not be found., NSUnderlyingError=0x71ca730 "A server with the specified hostname could not be found."
```

Comment: Just want to confirm that I'm also experiencing this on Heroku ATM. (And my dyno isn't sleeping)

Comment: This is not (exclusively) Heroku related, I am seeing the same thing with different platforms.

Comment: We are also seeing this with Heroku backend, and iOS client. Dynos are not sleeping, request is not hitting Heroku. @Michael Guren let me know if you found a root cause.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are being hit by a Dyno sleep behaviour. Please check [this documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos), specially the section **Dyno sleeping** and make sure you understand it.
Also there are several ways to keep the app on, like pinging the site regularly.

Another option is DNS, create an Ad-Hoc network on your computer and connect your iphone to that network. Use wireshark to make a network capture and analyse the DNS and HTTP responses.

Comment: I appreciate the response, but it is not a dyno sleeping issue.  I have a refresh button on my iOS app and I can hit refresh repeatedly about 15-20 times within 1 minute and, sporadically, one of those refreshes results in a hostname not found error.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a DNS issue on the network to which your iPhone/iPad is connected. To be sure, try any of the following:

1) Change your host name to an IP address instead of a string hostname, and add a Host: header to the HTTP request.

2) If (1) is hard, set your iPhone's DNS to a PC on your LAN, and install a DNS server on that PC, and serve at least that specific address directly from the PC (don't recurse for that domain).

Comment: Isn't it something which has to be tuned at heroku side ?

Comment: You cannot use a hardcoded IP with heroku as far as I know. If you do nslookup myapp.herokuapp.com you'll get a different IP almost every time. Heroku returns the IP address of a router which then gets the request and forwards it on to the real server.

Answer (score 0):

Your url = https://xxx.herokuapp.com/api/v1/matchups

Did you explicitly specify your subdomain xxx with your domain provider to direct to your server IP?

If not, try add a new A record with your subdomain xxx point to your server IP.

Hope that helps.